# "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!" while converting list of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

```
A=[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['10'], ['11'], ['12'], ['13'], ['14'], ['15'], ['16'], ['17'], ['18'], ['19'], ['20'], ['21'], ['22'], ['23'], ['24'], ['25'], ['26'], ['27'], ['29'], ['30'], ['31'], ['32'], ['33'], ['34'], ['35'], ['36']]

B=[['Andaman and Nicobar Islands', ' '], ['Andhra Pradesh'], ['Arunachal Pradesh'], ['Assam'], ['Bihar'], ['Chandigarh', ' '], ['Chhattisgarh'], ['Dadra and Nagar Haveli', ' '], ['Daman and Diu', ' '], ['National Capital Territory of Delhi', ' '], ['Goa'], ['Gujarat'], ['Haryana'], ['Himachal Pradesh'], ['Jammu and Kashmir'], ['Jharkhand'], ['Karnataka'], ['Kerala'], ['Lakshadweep', ' '], ['Madhya Pradesh'], ['Maharashtra'], ['Manipur'], ['Meghalaya'], ['Mizoram'], ['Nagaland'], ['Odisha'], ['Puducherry', ' '], ['Rajasthan'], ['Sikkim'], ['Tamil Nadu'], ['Telangana'], ['Tripura'], ['Uttar Pradesh'], ['Uttarakhand'], ['West Bengal']]

C=[['Port Blair'], ['Hyderabad', ' ', '(', 'de jure', ' to 2024)', '\n', 'Amaravati', ' ', '(', 'de facto', ' from 2017)', '[3]', ' ', '[4]', ' ', '[a]'], ['Itanagar'], ['Dispur'], ['Patna'], ['Chandigarh', '[c]'], ['Naya Raipur', '[d]'], ['Silvassa'], ['Daman'], ['New Delhi'], ['Panaji', '[e]'], ['Gandhinagar'], ['Chandigarh'], ['Shimla', '\n', 'Dharamshala', ' (W/2nd)', '[8]', '\n'], ['Srinagar', '\xa0(Summer)', '\n', 'Jammu', '\xa0(Winter)'], ['Ranchi'], ['Bengaluru'], ['Thiruvananthapuram'], ['Kavaratti'], ['Bhopal'], ['Mumbai', '[g]', '\n', 'Nagpur', '\xa0(W/2nd)', '[h]'], ['Imphal'], ['Shillong'], ['Aizawl'], ['Kohima'], ['Bhubaneswar'], ['Puducherry'], ['Jaipur'], ['Gangtok', '[j]'], ['Chennai', '[k]'], ['Hyderabad', '[l]'], ['Agartala'], ['Lucknow'], ['Dehradun', '[m]'], ['Kolkata']]
```

I have the above three lists and I want it to convert them to a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
Numbers State/UT Capital
1 Andaman and Nicobar Islands Port Blair
2 Andhra Pradesh Hyderabad
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools` and `zip` to help with this:

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': list(chain.from_iterable(A)),
                   'State/UT Capital': [' '.join([i[0], j[0]]) for i, j in zip(B, C)]})
```

Result:

```
   Numbers                               State/UT Capital
0        1         Andaman and Nicobar Islands Port Blair
1        2                       Andhra Pradesh Hyderabad
2        3                     Arunachal Pradesh Itanagar
3        4                                   Assam Dispur
.........
```